# How to extract an element of the array (Share object)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm trying to print just 1 element of the response (see below) when performing say a List Workspace Shares - eg. I would like to print just the email.

I have tried response.data[email], response.email to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks,

Sean

From the SDK docs.

{
"pageNumber": 1,
"pageSize": 100,
"totalPages": 1,
"totalCount": 2,
"data": [
{
"id": "AAAQSF82FOeE",
"type": "USER",
"userId": 4583173393803140,
"email": "john.doe@smartsheet.com",
"name": "John Doe",
"accessLevel": "OWNER",
"scope": "ITEM",
"createdAt": "2016-02-17T22:24:09Z",
"modifiedAt": "2016-02-17T22:24:09Z"
},
{
"id": "AQAISF82FOeE",
"type": "GROUP",
"groupId": 2331373580117892,
"name": "Group 1",
"accessLevel": "ADMIN",
"scope": "ITEM",
"createdAt": "2016-02-17T22:24:09Z",
"modifiedAt": "2016-02-17T22:25:08Z"
}
]

Answer (score 0):

Data is an array so you need to get the first item and only then the email, it should looks something like :

```
response.data[0].email
```